# How to get the reference of one variable of one class in another class in python?

Tags: python, class, reference

I have a class C1, and another class C2 which takes one instance of C1 as a variable. If I want to get the variable of C1 in C2, I have to use `self.c1.variable`. How can I get a reference of the variable of C1 in C2 so that I can get it directly?

```
class C1():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.variable = a

class C2():
    def __init__(self, c1):
        self.c1 = c1

    def print_variable(self):
        print self.c1.variable


c1 = C1(1)
c2 = C2(c1)
c2.print_variable()
```

Comment: can you explain more about what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @trahane I just want to use a shorter code to get c1.variable. If I have the third class C3 which contains C2, I have to access c1's variable in C3 via self.c2.c1.variable. That's not a good way if I want to use this variable frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@property` decorator to achieve that:

```
class C2():
    def __init__(self, c1):
        self.c1 = c1

    @property
    def variable(self):
        return self.c1.variable
```

In case you want to modify the `variable` in C2 instance:

```
    @variable.setter
    def variable(self, value):
        self.c1.variable = value
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I want.